# How to get JSON data out of JSON Array?

Tags: android, json, android-volley, android-json

I am using the Volley libary to understand working with  JSON data, i have successfully retrieved some data and would like to know how to get the individual  data out of my json array? I have tried doing what user's suggested on previous stackover flow post but only the json array data is showing up

```
@Override
public void downloadJson() {

    final String url = "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/2";
    JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("message");
                        Log.i("jsonArray", jsonArray.toString());

                        for(int i=0;  i>jsonArray.length(); i++){

                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            Log.i("obj", object.toString());


                        }



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }
    );

    requestQueue.add(getRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

exactly i can't understand your question .
but in your code there are some problem . 
in below you can see my proposal code .

```
for(int i=0;  i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
    Log.i("obj", jsonArray.get(i).toString());
}
```

in this code you can get each data from you'r JSONArray and use that URL to load image.
if this is not answer to you'r question i will be glad if you give some explanation about you'r question.

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake in your for loop,

```
for(int i=0;  i<jsonArray.length(); i++){ 

 JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
 Log.i("obj", object.toString());

}
```

Hope it will help!!